# validate if user select items or not in combobox in Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js, validation

I have combobox in Vue JS to select multiple items, I want to validate if user select any items or keep it empty, but the problem when I print the **length and value of combox** in console always gives **length == 2** and **values gives undefined** in both cases if user select items or not

HTML

```
 <v-col cols="6">
        <v-combobox  class="xrfelements" :items="xrfElementsRatios" v-model="mainElementsRatios" :rules="notEmptyRule" label="Main Elements and Ratios" multiple required small-chips outlined dense></v-combobox>
  </v-col>
```

java script

```
validateForm: function (e) {
if (document.getElementsByClassName("xrfelements").length) {
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("xrfelements".values
return true;}

 this.errors = [];
if (!document.getElementsByClassName("xrfelements").length){

       console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("xrfelements").index)
       console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("xrfelements".values)
        this.errors.push('there is no element selected.')
}
 

if (this.errors.length)
      

      {  
       this.$alert ("The following items should not be empty: " +this.errors.join(", "))

      }

    e.preventDefault(e);
      },
```

Comment: "xrfelements".values is incorrect syntax (to achieve what you want) :) Maybe put document.getElementsByClassName("xrfelements") inside a variable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how frameworks like vue work: You often times don't interact with  the DOM directly. Instead, you use Vue intermediary. Please learn the basics of Vue.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: ` <v-col cols="6">
        <v-combobox  class="xrfelements" :items="xrfElementsRatios" v-model="mainElementsRatios" :rules="notEmptyRule" label="Main Elements and Ratios" multiple required small-chips outlined dense></v-combobox>
  </v-col>`,
    data() {
        return {
          notEmptyRule: [],
          mainElementsRatios: [],
          xrfElementsRatios: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        validateForm: function (e) {
            if (mainElementsRatios.length) {
                console.log(mainElementsRatios);
              return true;
            }

            this.errors = [];
            if (!mainElementsRatios.length) {

                console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("xrfelements").index)
                console.log(mainElementsRatios)
    this.errors.push('there is no element selected.')
}


            if (this.errors.length) {
                this.$alert("The following items should not be empty: " + this.errors.join(", "))

            }

            e.preventDefault(e);
        },
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```